# How to paginate blog posts in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

I tried the following code but it doesn't work

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    #@entry_pages = Paginator.new(self, Entry.count, 10, params[:page])
    @entries = Entry.find(:all,
    #:limit => @entry_pages.items_per_page,
    #:offset => @entry_pages.current.offset,
    :order => 'entries.created_at DESC',
    :include => :user)
  end
end
```

This is the blog view

```
<h1>Recently updated blogs</h1>
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>
<p>
<%= link_to entry.user.username, entries_url(:user_id => entry.user) %><br />
'<%= entry.title %>' was posted <%= time_ago_in_words(entry.created_at) %> ago
</p>
<% end %>
```

I want the items to be paginated like this:

```
<<  [1][2][3]  >>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Give the [will_paginate](http://wiki.github.com/mislav/will_paginate) GEM a try.
It provides all the features you need to paginate your blog entries.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the **paginating_find** plugin.  Here's a tutorial:

http://www.igvita.com/2006/09/10/faster-pagination-in-rails/

Looks like it's now hosted on github.com:

http://github.com/alexkwolfe/paginating_find/tree/master